# generic timed event viewer/visualization

Tags: events, logging, viewer

My application generates a bunch of events at different moments.  Events have a timestamp, a duration, a type (error/warning/normal), a description, etc.

Is there any application which can take in data (probably from xml files) containing this type of event information, and displays in in a table, with search range by date, etc?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you log directly to a database instead?

Comment: If I did, would there be a viewer tool which can help me?

Comment: you can resort to any report engine you like. I can't suggest one without knowing what language and database are you using.

Comment: if it is for ad-hoc queries, you can just link to your log database using ODBC and sort out data using MS Access or Excel.